# React-smooth-scrollbar overflow plugin not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, smooth-scrolling

Trying to get overflow plugin working.
I have the smooth scroll working but getting an error with the plugin. The github shows this to do this

```
SmoothScrollbar.use(OverscrollPlugin); 

class App2 extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Scrollbar> ... </Scrollbar>
        );
    }
}
```

error i get

```
TypeError: _reactSmoothScrollbar.default.use is not a function
```

Comment: That looks like an import issue, Can you create a fiddle? (You can use https://codesandbox.io )

Comment: That was the issue. I didn't understand the error notification. cheers!

Comment: Good to hear that you solved your problem:) You can post an answer to your the question  and after 48 hours you can accept it, so people who wants to help can just see the answered icon and don't spend time on reading the question.